# JMeter - Sending .xml files as SOAP/XML Requests

Tags: xml, soap, jmeter

I'm very new to JMeter and that's my task:

I have some .xml files i intend to use as consecutive SOAP/XML Requests to a WebService in a single Test.

1. Can I do this without adding n sampler where n is the number of files? (I can't manage to do this with CSVs)
2. Is there a way to pass only the directory's name that contains those files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you can use [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) to avoid samplers duplication.

In regards to reading xml file names, you can use [Beanshell Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) to load files into variables and [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate through them. Example Beanshell code to store file names in a directory into variables will look as follows:

```
import java.io.File;

File xmldir = new File("/path/to/your/directory");
{
    int counter = 1;
    for (File xmlfile : xmldir.listFiles())
    {
        if (xmlfile.getName().endsWith(".xml"))
        {
            vars.put("xmlfile_" + counter, xmlfile.getCanonicalPath());
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

It'll produce variables like:

```
xmlfile_1 = test1.xml
xmlfile_2 = test2.xml
xmlfile_N = testN.xml
etc.
```

which you will be able to iterate via ForEach Controller configured as follows:

- Input variable prefix: `xmlfile`
- Output variable name: anything meaningful, i.e. `currentfile`

So you should be able to refer your XML files as `${currentfile}` or `${__V(currentfile)}` in your SOAP requests.